# Displaying dynamic number of input tags

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jquery function that request data typed json.
The data I requested is an object (php),
and one of it's attribute is an array. Assume the attribute is $fruit.

This is the script:

```
<script>
//jquery script
function view(news_id) {
    $.post(
    BASE_URL+"/processes/news_detail.php",
    {id:news_id},
    function(data) {
        ...............................
        $("#news-detail").dialog("open");
    },
    "json"
);
}
</script>
```

My question is, how do I display input tags as many as the number of $fruit's count (dynamically)...

Thanks before...

Comment: can you make your question a bit clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
...
function(data) {
    ...
    $.each(data.fruit, function(i, currentFruit){ //i will contain current array index           
        $("#divContainer").append("<input type='text' id='fruit"+i+"' />");
    });
    ...
},
...
```

Hope this helps. Cheers